# how to give click event in directive using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, angularjs-ng-repeat

could you please tell me how to give click event in directive ? I make one chart using highchart.js  (bar chart) .i want to give click event in that chart ?

I found using jquery they give like that .but how we can give in our directive ? click event example

http://jsfiddle.net/b4n9z19v/

How we give click event in out directive ? 
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/FtDfeyd6fjHL3RNwzyCn?p=preview

```
.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            chartData: "=value",
            chartObj: "=?"
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            //Update when charts data changes
            $scope.$watch('chartData', function(value) {
                if (!value)
                    return;

                // Initiate the chartData.chart if it doesn't exist yet
                $scope.chartData.chart = $scope.chartData.chart || {};

                // use default values if nothing is specified in the given settings
                $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo = $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo || $element[0];
                if ($attrs.type)
                    $scope.chartData.chart.type = $scope.chartData.chart.type || $attrs.type;
                if ($attrs.height)
                    $scope.chartData.chart.height = $scope.chartData.chart.height || $attrs.height;
                if ($attrs.width)
                    $scope.chartData.chart.width = $scope.chartData.chart.type || $attrs.width;

                $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
            });
        }
    };

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Here is the solution for your problem. If you are using an library, then they should provide call back or any other optional functions for you in angular.

If you don't find, and you find jquery you can use the same jquery functionality in angular using the same jquery code.

How do i do in Angular :-( ? Here in angular, Directives are used.

**Code is below:**

> Html

```
<div directive-name id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

> Directive

```
    .directive("directiveName", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
             var char=$attributes.id;

             $("#"+char).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {
                                alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }]
        });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Working plunkr for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/T5dPVVGE0E2LMUMRnDEX?p=preview

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: Thanks for answer but it not working in my plunker why ?

Comment: You are using the element on click. Here element is the whole chart. So when you click on the chart, the whole is clicked. You need to find a call back function. Instead of mixing the angular with jquery in directive. Use plain jquery the way they explained. To pass the data use angualr model

Comment: You are mixing angular and jquery to get this. Use plain jquery like they said. Or ask for them how to use callback function for highcharts. Since it is paid version, I can't check further.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery example you are passing function directly like

```
click: function () {
                     alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                   }
```

But in angular example you passing as a JSON string. So it cannot able to parse the function .

```
"events": {
               "click": "function () {alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y)}"
}
```

So in your angular example pass the input directly like what you did in jquery example. Then your code will work.